# Can I create 2 "displays" on a headless server?

Tags: mac-mini, screen-sharing, dual-screen

I have 2 Mac Minis.  One is to be used as a headless server while the other is a general-purpose user desktop machine.  The user system has two monitors.  I have set up the server to allow screen sharing, which works fine to show its one display on one user monitor.

The question is whether there is a way to tell the server that it should pretend to have two displays (instead of pretending to have one) and allow those to show on corresponding user monitors.

Comment: The user system is Late 2012, server *says* 2018 but arrived new yesterday.  I'm not familiar with what you're suggesting...will Google.

Answer (score 1):

No, only one screen can be viewed at a time over Screen Sharing. However, if you have configured two screens, you can view each screen, one at a time, by selecting "Displays" from the "View" menu item in the screen sharing app on your User Mac.  This way you can switch which screen to view.

Comment: Not wonderful...maybe workable, but it begs the question of how to configure two screens without attaching two physical displays.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong. It is possible to view each screen on different monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Not without additional hardware. You will need at least an adaptor to create the second monitor port. Also, you would need to plug a dummy display emulator into the adaptor and another dummy display emulator into the HDMI port on the 2018 Mac mini.

The user can use to two monitors, each with a screen sharing window, but to do this the user has to open the Screen Sharing application once for each window.